# Randomly color paragraphs in LaTeX document

Tags: color, paragraphs

I usually type up my notes for school in LaTeX, and I find it easier to focus on text where the color changes between paragraphs, which is easy to do with old fashioned pen and paper.

On LaTeX, however, is there a way where the compiler can automatically do this while rendering my pdf changing the color of random paragraphs?

Answer (score 14):

You need no external package (except for `xcolor`) if you use pdfTeX or LuaTeX (not XeTeX) as engine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyhook,xcolor}

\newcommand{\randomcolor}{%
  \definecolor{randomcolor}{RGB}
   {
    \pdfuniformdeviate 256,
    \pdfuniformdeviate 256,
    \pdfuniformdeviate 256
   }%
  \color{randomcolor}%
}

\PushPostHook{par}{\randomcolor}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

One

Two

Three

\section{Second}

Four

Five

Six

\end{document}
```

The primitive `\pdfuniformdeviate` must be followed by an integer and expands to a uniformly distributed random integer between 0 (included) and the given number (excluded).

Using `everyhook` is safer than playing directly with `\everypar`.

[image]

Comment: Update: also XeTeX now has `\uniformdeviate`.

Answer (score 10):

**Solution Idea**

At the start of each paragraph, generate three random numbers between 0 and 255, use them as RGB parameters to generate a color, apply the color at the start of paragraph.

**The Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{insdljs}
\usepackage{rangen}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\randomlycolorparagraph{%
  % Get random color paramaters
  \RandomZ{\R}{0}{255}%\R
  \RandomZ{\G}{0}{255}%\G
  \RandomZ{\B}{0}{255}%\B
  % Generate random color
  \definecolor{randomcolor}{RGB}{\R,\G,\B}
  % Use color
  \color{randomcolor}}

\def\randomlycoloreveryparagraph{\everypar={\randomlycolorparagraph}}

\AtBeginDocument{\randomlycoloreveryparagraph}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

**Solution Details**

This solution uses the [rangen](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/rangen) package, specifically the `\RandomZ` command
to generate three random numbers between 0 and 255. These three numbers
are then used as RGB values in the 
`\definecolor` command from [xcolor](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor) package.

All the above are bundled in a macro which is applied at the start of a paragraph using the `\everypar` command.

I went one step further and hooked the 
`\everypar` with `\AtBeginDocument`. So, the random color effect starts
at the start of a document. Should you want the random effect start at some
mid point, please put the 
`\randomlycoloreveryparagraph` 
command where you want the *random* effect to start.

**The Output**

[image]

Your output is likely to look different. The colors are supposed to be random.

**Tips**

Should you want the RGB values in a certain range, tweak the range values
in the `\RandomZ` commands.

Comment: Good idea. But I don't have `insdljs` with my TeXlive 2013 full installed. According to CTAN *Con­tained in MiKTeX as acro­tex* it is only for MikTeX?

Comment: @Sigur This is not at all for MikTeX only. I also had to install it fresh in my Ubuntu machine. And I am always a command line guy.

Comment: in Overleaf, `rangen` doesn't seem to be installed by default.