# Color-coding a Dialogue - Alternate Paragraphs in Different tcolorboxes

Tags: tcolorbox, paragraphs

> - I would like to define a command `\dialoguestart{black!10}{black!25}` that starts setting the paragraphs into `tcolorboxes`, alternating between lighter (black!10) and darker (black!25) ones.
> - The default setting of paragraphs should be returned to after another command `\dialogueend`

**Edit:** After discussion with @Schrödinger's cat, @siracusa and @cfr it became clear that the initial question was too big and too unspecific. It emerged that a reasonable way to tackle the issue is using an environment and I have adjusted the post accordingly.

To illustrate, the snippet

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
%\input{solution_to_this_problem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\dialoguestart{black!10}{black!25}
\lipsum[75]
\lipsum[66]
\dialogueend
\lipsum[75]

\end{document}
```

should produce

[image]

The MWE below produces the desired result. It does not take me all the way, however, as the new environment can only handle one paragraph at a time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newif\iflight\lightfalse
\newcommand\toggleboxstart{%
    \iflight\begin{dark}%
    \else\begin{light}\fi}
\newcommand\toggleboxend{%
  \iflight\end{dark}\global\lightfalse%
  \else\end{light}\global\lighttrue\fi}
\newenvironment{toggling}[2]{%
    \newtcolorbox{light}{colback=#1,colframe=#1,sharp corners,breakable} 
    \newtcolorbox{dark}{colback=#2,colframe=#2,sharp corners,breakable}
    % something that ensures `\toggleboxend\toggleboxstart` being called between paragraphs
    }

\newcommand\dialoguestart[2]{\begin{toggling}{#1}{#2}\toggleboxstart}
\newcommand\dialogueend{\toggleboxend\end{toggling}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\dialoguestart{black!10}{black!25}
\lipsum[75]
\dialogueend                       % these two commands
\dialoguestart{black!10}{black!25} % I would like to avoid
\lipsum[66]
\dialogueend
\lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

To handle multiple paragraphs, `\toggleboxend` and `\toggleboxstart` have to be called  between paragraphs within the toggling environment. I have tried adding

```
\let\origpar\par
\let\origeverypar\everypar
\renewcommand\everypar{\origeverypar\toggleboxstart}
\renewcommand\par{\toggleboxend\origpar}
```

to the environment's definition, which throws `Paragraph ended before \renew@command was complete`. And pushing my commands using the {everyhook} package, which solved [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157014/randomly-color-paragraphs-in-latex-document?rq=1) similar to the one at hand

```
\usepackage{everyhook}
\newenvironment{toggling}[2]{%
    \newtcolorbox{light}{colback=#1,colframe=#1,sharp corners,breakable} 
    \newtcolorbox{dark}{colback=#2,colframe=#2,sharp corners,breakable}
    \PushPreHook{par}{\toggleboxstart}
    \PushPostHook{par}{\toggleboxend}
    }

\newcommand\dialoguestart[2]{\begin{toggling}{#1}{#2}} % no more \toggleboxstart
\newcommand\dialogueend{\end{toggling}}                % no more \toggleboxend
```

results in being prompted `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]`.
What else can I do to execute some code between paragraphs? Within the environment, there will only be plain text.

---

**Edit** (by *jakun* who started the second bounty):
My attempt to copy and paste my code into the bounty description did not work out well so I post it here again for better readability:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newif\iflight

\newenvironment{toggling}[2]{%
    \newcommand\toggleboxstart{%
        \iflight
            %(BEGIN LIGHT)
            \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=#1,colframe=#1,sharp corners,breakable]%
        \else
            %(BEGIN DARK)
            \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=#2,colframe=#2,sharp corners,breakable]%
        \fi
    }%
    \newcommand\toggleboxend{%
        \end{tcolorbox}\relax
        %(END)
        \iflight
            \global\lightfalse
        \else
            \global\lighttrue
        \fi
    }%
    \toggleboxstart
    \everypar{\toggleboxend\toggleboxstart}%
}{%
    \toggleboxend
}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[66]
    \begin{toggling}{black!10}{black!25}
    \lipsum[75]

    \lipsum[66]

    \lipsum[66]
    \end{toggling}
    \lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

This code fails with

> LaTeX Error: \begin{tcolorbox} on input line 36 ended by \end{tcb@savebox}.

or

> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

when commenting out the optional arguments of `\begin{tcolorbox}`.

Why does this not work and how could one make it work?

(When commenting out the `\begin{tcolorbox}` and `\end{tcolorbox}` and commenting in the test text in parentheses I get the expected output.)

**Edit**: I am using the following versions (`grep -i version main.log`):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.11.15)  25 NOV 2019 21:59
Package: tcolorbox 2019/09/19 version 4.21 text color boxes
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbbreakable.code.tex' version '4.21'
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
```

I have tried using tcolorbox 2019/11/15 version 4.22 instead and get the same result.

Comment: Maybe something like `\everypar` would be a way to go, see e.g. this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119760.

Comment: I have tried modifying `\everypar` to begin and `\par` to end the respective environments. But both commands are called too often by LaTeX itself. My code now causes too many problems for me to fix. This might work, but goes beyond my knowledge and does not yet produce an  MWE...

Comment: Could you add a MWE that demonstrates how your colorboxes should be used, and some example code that shows what contexts the paragraph hook should be able to "survive"?

Comment: I feel that this will require major efforts to produce something that most likely never will be fully robust. How much resistance do you have to having to add some very short macro or whatever at the end of each paragraph? (@siracusa You need to load `tcolorbox` with the `breakable` option to make the above boxes work.)

Comment: @Schrödinger Quite some resistance. Adding macros is less clumsy than putting everything in environments, as I do now, but it still feels clumsy. That said, if you feel this is the only robust way, I will have to live with it.

Comment: @D.Roepo Are the standard sectioning commands and plain paragraphs the only code that apprears in your document? For exmaple, what about `\parbox`es, minipages, other tcolorboxes etc.? The problem with the `\everypar`/`\par` approach is that it quickly breaks, because `\par` is used under different names in various places, e.g. `\@@par` in the base or `\endgraf` in `lipsum`.

Comment: @siracusa In the actual document there are plenty of `{minipages}` and other `{tcolorboxes}`. I am also playing with the `titlesec` package to customize my sectioning commands. `\everypar` & `\par` is thus probably not the way to go.

Comment: If you're redefining the sectioning commands, then that will complicate things because you want to redefine them again to add a hook ending the highlighting. If you were willing to use an environment `\begin{highlightingpars} ... [lots of paragraphs] \end{highlightingpars}` that would be easier and potentially less fragile. (It depends what you want to highlight. Does that material itself include `tcolorbox`es, for example?) Right now, I think this question is either too big (i.e. can't be reasonably done here) or ill-defined (i.e. there are constraints we don't know).

Comment: @cfr The question is probably both, too big and ill-defined. Due to me not knowing enough of the LaTeX internals, I did not know all the implications it entails at the time of asking. An environment would be very nice indeed. It is just two commands (like `\higlightdialogue`and `\enddialogue` would have been). The sectioning commands not automatically ending the highlighting is something easy to live with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why but I couldn't get it running easily with `\everypar`.
(Inserting a dummy text between paragraphs worked perfectly but replacing that dummy text with `\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}` caused an `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.` error.)

Instead I am offering a different approach based on replacing paragraph ends with delimited arguments.
It has the disadvantage of being less efficient and that the entire "environment" body is read before hand. So don't try to use anything which relies on changing catcodes like the `\verb` command inside it.
But the implementation is fairly easy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

% soluton_to_this_problem START
\long\def\dialoguestart#1#2#3\dialogueend{% #1: color 1, #2: color 2, #3: body
    \dialogueiter{#1}{#2}#3\par\dialogueend
}

\long\def\dialogueiter#1#2#3\par#4\dialogueend{% #1: this color, #2: alternative color, #3: next paragraph, #4: rest of body
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=#1,colframe=#1,sharp corners,breakable]
        #3
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax
        % #4 is empty => finish
    \else
        % note how I have swapped #1 and #2 to toggle the colors
        \dialogueiter{#2}{#1}#4\dialogueend
    \fi
}
% soluton_to_this_problem END

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\dialoguestart{black!10}{black!25}
\lipsum[75]

\lipsum[66]

\lipsum[66]
\dialogueend
\lipsum[75]

\end{document}
```

`\dialoguestart` is just a wrapper around the `\dialogueiter` macro in order to avoid an error if the argument does not contain a paragraph end (end of paragraph = empty line = `\par`).

`\dialogueiter` is the macro which is doing the real job. It splits the argument in two with an argument delimiter. The first part is the next paragraph, the second part is the remaining rest.
If the remaining rest is not empty `\dialogueiter` uses recursion to process it further.

`\dialogueend` is just an argument delimiter and is never expanded or executed.

[image]

---

Update: 
The [xparse package](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides (among others) the `\NewDocumentCommand` macro which is far more powerful than the LaTeX2e `\newcommand` macro by allowing to have delimited arguments (which is why I did not use `\newcommand` for this answer) and several optional arguments. Also it is more comfortable than the TeX primitive `\def` (which I used above) in this case because it supports optional arguments.

`\NewDocumentCommand` is also safer than `\def` because it checks whether a macro of that name exists already and prints an error if it does instead of silently overwriting the existing macro.

(If you wanted to implement optional arguments with `\def` you could lookahead for the next token with `\kernel@ifnextchar` and then use either a macro which expects this argument or another macro which does not.)

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dialoguestart}{O{black!10} O{black!25} +u\dialogueend}{% [#1: color 1], [#2: color 2], #3: body
    \dialogueiter[#1][#2]#3\par\dialogueend
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dialogueiter}{r[] r[] u\par +u\dialogueend}{% #1: this color, #2: alternative color, #3: next paragraph, #4: rest of body
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=#1,colframe=#1,sharp corners,breakable]
        #3
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#4}\relax
        % #4 is empty => finish
    \else
        % note how I have swapped #1 and #2 to toggle the colors
        \dialogueiter[#2][#1]#4\dialogueend
    \fi
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm. How could `\dialogestart` be redefined to have the colors being optional arguments defaulting to black!10 and black!25?

Comment: @D.Roepo please see my updated answer

Comment: @jakun Re your new bounty code: What `tcolorbox` version are you using? I can't reproduce the error with 4.22 by just commenting out the optional parameters (though the output is wrong).